# Create accessible dropdown lists in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

A few of my users are blind and therefore use assistive technologies - mainly screen readers. Since I am working on a Mac, I also have access to VoiceOver, which I use to look at what my site "sounds" like. And one thing that is definitively off are dropdowns.

When I highlight a menu entry, it announces the text, and says "Link" - which is very misleading. What `role=""` do I have to supply, or what other things, to make it announce the element correctly?

By the way, I am already using Paypal's accessibility plugin.

Comment: Which bootstrap dropdown are you using? This one works quite well and uses the best roles for dropdowns - namely the menu roles http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: You can look at the source code here: http://git.ingwie.me/ingwie/bird3/blob/master/themes/dragonsinn/views/layouts/main.php#L88 The output can be seen at http://dev.dragonsinn.tk . I recommend using the browser's dev-tools, because I am compacting my HTML.

Comment: looks like you just need to update to 3.3.1, you are using 3.2

Answer (score 1):

**I use Smartmenus from smartmenus.org.** They have examples on how to add their javascript to make also bootstrap menus (navbar) assistive. You'll find the examples inside the downloaded ZIP.

You can also test how this will work by just going to their site. If their menu reads like you want to, then that solution may be the most easy.

I use it mostly to get a **fully keyboard operated menu system**, and it is easy to duplicate the use for new sites once I got the hang of it. But they say they support "all" assistive technology for websites if I am not mistaken.

I use it with jquery 1.11.1 and bootstrap navbar. It needs you to add a class and a id to your

I use jquery selectors right under the

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-inner">
    <ul> <!-- my ul li list is here-->
    </div>
</nav>
    <script>
    $("nav ul").first().addClass('myownclass-for-styling sm sm-simple').attr('id', 'main-menu');            
    </script>
```

In the head I add jquery 1.11.1 and the bootstrap css + the required css from smartmenus:

```
<link href="myCDN/smartmenus/css/sm-core-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="myCDN/smartmenus/css/sm-simple/sm-simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I use the sm-simple.css that I custimized a lot for my ues. They have a css made for co-working with Bootstrap css, so try that one.

In the very bottom of the page I load the javascript needed (for all assistive technology I believe):

```
<!-- SmartMenus jQuery plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn2.flexweb.no/smartmenus/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>

<!-- SmartMenus jQuery Keyboard Addon -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myCDN/smartmenus/addons/keyboard/jquery.smartmenus.keyboard.js"></script>

<!-- SmartMenus jQuery init -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
            subMenusSubOffsetX: 1,
            subMenusSubOffsetY: -8
        });
        $('#main-menu').smartmenus('keyboardSetHotkey', '123', 'shiftKey');
    });
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    addonScriptSrc = [ ['SmartMenus jQuery Keyboard Addon', 'http://myCDN/smartmenus/addons/keyboard/jquery.smartmenus.keyboard.js'] ];
    addonScriptInit = "\t\t$('#main-menu').smartmenus('keyboardSetHotkey', 123, 'shiftKey');\n";
  </script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a very fine menu solution indeed - it looks really nice and has a very good keyboard navigation. Unfortunately, it does not read like I had hoped. The top-level entries are read as links and not announced to be menu entries - or even haivng sub-menus. Still, a very impressive menu i will bookmark nevertheless. Thanks for the pointing out!